# Subquery in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

MS Access query edited:

I have 3 columns in a table: Col A: dates (of which there are 4 different ones), Col B: fruit (6 types) and col C: count of fruit

I would like to get a list of the unique dates, the sum of the unique fruits sold on that date and the sum of the total number of pieces of fruit sold on that date

e.g. 01/01/2018 (col A) there would be 6 pieces of fruit (col B) and 100 sales in total (col C)

So the unique dates, the number of unique fruit sold on that date and the sum of all pieces of fruit sold on that date

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can edit the question and show your Postgres query.  Sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS Access?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you way, the query is a simple `group by`:

```
select date, fruit, sum(cnt)
from t
group by date, fruit
order by date, fruit;
```

This is pretty much exactly the same query as in Postgres, or any other database or system that supports SQL.

Comment: Thanks for this, but it does not give me a unique list of dates. Sorry I should have been more specific. I was looking for the number of each fruit against a list of the 4 unique dates

Comment: Just tried and can't seem to get it working either. But what I was trying to do was to get a list of the distinct dates and then against those dates get count of the number of fruits and the sum of the number of fruits that were sold on that date - I will re-write the main question

Comment: @Gandalfrandalf . . . Normally, I discourage rewriting questions after they have been answered.  You might consider deleting this question and asking a new one.  In this case, no hard feelings if you edit the question, because the purpose of my answer was to prompt more details from you.

Comment: Sorry - have edited but if you think it would be better I'll ask the question again?